# changing cursor with pointer events

Tags: javascript, css, pointers

So I have this canvas that I have been working on for the last couple of weeks and finally getting things in order. I am using `pointer-events: none;` on the top 3 canvas's and then `pointer-events: auto;` on the bottom canvas that I am looking at to set the cursor position. But, the cursor is the wrong one. It looks like the move cursor (right above the G in the word testing). I need it to look like the `text` cursor. So my question is: Is there a way to continue to use the `pointer-events` and still have the `text` cursor when I am hovering over the sign? If this is a simple fix I apologize I don't know all that much about `pointer-events`. What I could find said to add a div around the html I want to change the text cursor to and then set that divs cursor style to `text` which didn't give me the desired effect.

> What I did:

```
<div style="cursor: text">
   <canvas1 style=pointer-events: none;> 
   <canvas2 style=pointer-events: none;>
   <canvas3 style=pointer-events: none;>
   <canvas1 style=pointer-events: auto;>
</div>
```

^^^This is what the examples I have found said to do and this did not give me the right cursor

[image: Move cursor]

> HTML:

```
<div class="text-area" ng-class="{'tc-pointer-none':vm.scope.isReadOnly}">
    <div id="{{vm.isTextArea ? vm.textAreaId : vm.formIdentifier+'phase'+ vm.phaseIndex}}matrixCore" tabindex="0"
         ng-keydown="vm.onKeyDown($event)" ng-keypress="vm.onType($event)" ng-focus="vm.isEditable=true"
         ng-blur="vm.isEditable=false">



        <!-- Shows cursor -->
        <div class="text-cursor" style="cursor: text">
            <div class="sign">
                <div id="{{vm.isTextArea?vm.textAreaId : vm.formIdentifier + 'phase' + vm.phaseIndex}}cursor1"
                     class="cursor cursor-canvas"
                     ng-style="{'opacity':(vm.scope.isReadOnly || !vm.isEditable)?'0':'1'}">
                </div>
                <!-- End shows cursor -->

                <!-- Shows text -->
                <canvas class="text-canvas" id="{{vm.canvas_uuid}}"></canvas>
                <!-- End shows text -->

                <!-- Shows LED canvas-->
                <div id="{{vm.baseDiv_uuid}}" class="base-canvas">
                    <!--ng-style="{top:vm.isTextArea}">-->
                    <canvas id="{{vm.baseCanvas_uuid}}"></canvas>
                </div>
                <!-- End shows LED canvas -->
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

> CSS:

```
/* Matrix */

.cursor-canvas .special-canvas {
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
}

.base-canvas {
    z-index: 2;
    pointer-events: auto;
    position: absolute;
    outline: none;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
}

.cursor-canvas {
    z-index: 4;
    height: 80px;
    position: absolute;
    outline: none;
    pointer-events: none;
}
.base-canvas .special-canvas .text-area .cursor-canvas {
    cursor: text;
}

.text-canvas {
    z-index: 3;
    pointer-events: none;
}

.text-area {
    pointer-events: none;
    font-size: 0;
}

.sign {
    position: relative;
}


/* End matrix */
```